# Creating New Row Each Update to Parse on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I scoured StackOverflow and Parse's documentation and support, and could not find the answer, though I am sure it is quite obvious for someone versed in databases. In my Android app, I am creating the same-named ParseObject for all users, and then adding a user key with the Android's Secure.ANDROID_ID. As I periodically fetch the user's location, I want to add that user's new latitude and longitude to my Parse table.

My issue is that instead of creating a new row that contains the user_id, lat, long, the lat and long is being *overwritten*. How can I ensure that upon each new location update, the table creates a new row entry?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may want to re-read docs from REST API on 'relations' and 'arrays' and 'users' before you go to far with a physical design. each time a device reports GPS you can just make a dumb row in a timestamped location table and then update the USER's collection object to Point to the other object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rest api docs show examples on 'game scores' where they use pointers and relation to link each new reported score back to the user&game.

That relates pretty well to your scenario with reported  GPS locations.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think that ParseObject theObject = new ParseObject("Table") created a new row each time, but rather a new table. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.